# Struggling to understand Codeforces UI/Platform

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

So, I've been practicing Data Structures and Algorithms on Leetcode for over two years now. Recently, I decided to try the Codeforces platform. But the website looks extremely run-down and crumbling.

Besides, are we required to solve the entire thing on our own, like having to **implement the entire binary tree** with nodes instead of only completing the required function? Like how do I even create nodes each time when solving a problem? It's going to take forever, isn't it?

I was expecting a cleaner interface that doesn't look like it's the WWW from the 90s.

Comment: Use inbuilt tree structures that your language provides.

Answer (score 2):

The website design of Codeforces might not be as cutting-edge or eye-catching as that of some other platforms. Because it is created with a focus on the fundamentals of competitive programming: problem-solving and effective coding. This simplistic method is preferred by many competitive programmers because it minimizes distractions and places more emphasis on problem-solving.

Also, you are usually required to implement the entire solution. This is more reflective of the kind of problem-solving you might encounter in coding competitions or real-world coding interviews.